# Bytes to String, without decoding

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python3 and i need to get incoming bytes from a socket and store it as a string.

```
print(input_bytes)
b'data:\x00,\xff'
```

I don't need to decode the data

```
byte_input_to_string = input_bytes

print(byte_input_to_string)
b'data:\x00,\xff'

file = open('byte_data.txt','w')
file.write(byte_input_to_string)
file.close()
```

What i need is to store data as a string, i don't need to decode it. I just want the same data but as a string, so i can parse it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file.write(str(byte_input_to_string))
```

Comment: If you want delete ``b'`` and final ``'`` try use ``replace`` function is so easy, doesn't forget addme how correct answer, thanks for read.

Answer (score -1):

If the data you are receiving are text, probably they are encoded in utf-8 (or other encoding).

If the are raw data, there is an encoding that mantains all the characters with ASCII code from 0 to 255:

> data = data.decode("latin1")

This changes the data type from bytes to str, preserving the characters AS-IS.

It isn't a brilliant solution because it consumes cpu time and memory, creating a new object, but it is the only one.

**It is a nuisance there isn't an instruction in Python to just change the data type, from bytes to str, without processing.**